# Transfer Checked Datagrid Values to a Textbox From Another Form

Tags: c#, datagrid

I'm trying to make program related to sending messages to multiple contacts. The program is connected to a database, and contacts are stored there. What I did was create a phonebook form that includes a datagrid displaying the info and a button "Add Selected as Recipients". When clicked, it is supposed to display the checked phone numbers to a textbox from another form. But whenever I check more than 1 box, the second number overlaps the first. These are my codes:

"Add Selected as Recipients" button:

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addcon a = new addcon();
        sendMsg sm = new sendMsg();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            isCellChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
            if (isCellChecked == true)
            {
                sm.txtDstNo.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value) + ";"; 
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully added.", "Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                sm.Show();

            }
        }


    }
```